# Is it good to call `router.use` inside `app.use`?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a little doubt. I need to make a maintainable API structure, so thought in a good one, but it's having some "ugly" code, and I don't know if it is a good practice to call several `route.use()`, inside an `app.use`:

```
├── server.js
├── routes
│   ├── v1
│   │   ├── v1.js
│   │   ├── users
│   │   │   ├── index.js
...
```

So, in practice, it will work this way:

### Server.js

This file will call the `v1.js`, like this:

```
const v1 = require('./routes/v1/v1');
app.use('/v1', v1); <-- First "app.use()"
```

### v1.js

Will call all routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const users = require("./v1/users");
router.use(users); <-- "router.use()" when inside "app.use()" 
...
module.exports = router;
```

### users/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const users = require('../../../controllers/User/user.controller.js');

router.get('/user/test', users.test);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I think that's a common way of structuring routes with Express. So, there shouldn't be any issues with this.

Comment: That is what express.Router() method is for anyways. Structuring the express as per you need.